# How to avoid exception "Could not find or create a new EntityManager!" when using JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase with sessionPersistence is false

Tags: java, entitymanager, jbpm

I test jbpm process with using JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase (jbpm-test.6.5.0.Final-redhat-7) with constructor super(true, false).
Second parametr, sessionPersistence = false but get error when invoke method kSession.startProcess  :

````
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find or create a new EntityManager!
    at org.jbpm.process.audit.JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger.getEntityManager(JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger.java:246)
    at org.jbpm.process.audit.JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger.persist(JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger.java:201)
    at org.jbpm.process.audit.JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger.afterVariableChanged(JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger.java:132)
    at org.drools.core.event.ProcessEventSupport.fireAfterVariableChanged(ProcessEventSupport.java:154)
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.context.variable.VariableScopeInstance.setVariable(VariableScopeInstance.java:92)
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.AbstractProcessInstanceFactory.createProcessInstance(AbstractProcessInstanceFactory.java:59)
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcess(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:256)
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.createProcessInstance(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:238)
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.createProcessInstance(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:197)
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcess(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:187)
    at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcess(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:182)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.startProcess(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1901)
    at org.rshb.collection.hardcollect.plan.action.bankruptcy.propertysale.travelRestriction.TestStep1091.restrictionTest(TestStep1091.java:97).```

But if inspect  JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase we could see that just when sessionPersistence = true will invoke JPAWorkingMemoryDBLogger.

this my test: ```
public class TestStep1091 extends JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase {
    private final ActionPlanItem step261091Api = new ActionPlanItem();

    public TestStep1091() {
        super(true, false);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws NamingException, SystemException, NotSupportedException {
        step261091Api.setName("Внести информацию о рассмотрении судом ходатайства о временном ограничении права должника на выезд из РФ");
        step261091Api.setRefId(261091);
    }

 @Test
    public void restrictionTest() {
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();
        // Add  BPMN files to the KieFileSystem
        kfs.write("src/main/resources/hardcollect/TravelRestrictionsStep.bpmn2",
                ks.getResources().newClassPathResource("org/rshb/collection/hardcollect/plan/action/bankruptcy/propertysale/travelRestrictions/TravelRestrictionsStep.bpmn2"));
        kfs.write("src/main/resources/hardcollect/SAVE.bpmn2",
                ks.getResources().newClassPathResource("org/rshb/collection/hardcollect/common/SAVE.bpmn2"));
        kfs.write("src/main/resources/hardcollect/RETRIEVE.bpmn2",
                ks.getResources().newClassPathResource("org/rshb/collection/hardcollect/common/RETRIEVE.bpmn2"));
        kfs.write("src/main/resources/hardcollect/GetDueDate.bpmn2",
                ks.getResources().newClassPathResource("org/rshb/collection/hardcollect/plan/GetDueDate.bpmn2"));

        KieBuilder kieBuilder = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs).buildAll();
        KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(kieBuilder.getKieModule().getReleaseId());

        RuntimeEnvironment environment = RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.Factory.get()
                .newDefaultBuilder()
                .persistence(false)
                    //   .entityManagerFactory(getEmf())
                .knowledgeBase(kContainer.getKieBase())
                .get();

        RuntimeManager manager = RuntimeManagerFactory.Factory.get().newPerProcessInstanceRuntimeManager(environment);
        RuntimeEngine runtimeEngine = manager.getRuntimeEngine(ProcessInstanceIdContext.get());
        KieSession kSession = runtimeEngine.getKieSession();
        try {
            ProcessInstance processInstance = kSession.startProcess("hardcollect.TravelRestrictionsStep", getProcessParams());
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(runtimeEngine);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        manager.disposeRuntimeEngine(runtimeEngine);
    }
}
````

I think this could be related with default builder  .newDefaultBuilder() im RuntimeEnviroment.